# Are there any iPad accessories that vibrate, for silent alarms?

Tags: ipad, hardware-recommendation, vibrate

Are there any iPad accessories that vibrate, to permit the same kind of silent notification iPhones can?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not.
The OS would have to have support for said accessories, and anyway, there are no accessories for vibration.

You can submit feedback to Apple on the iPad [here](http://www.apple.com/feedback/ipad.html), but they won't respond and it might take them some time to implement the feature (if they ever do).